# Azure cosmos Db when create a new document return sometimes One or more errors occurred

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I use SQL Api from azure cosmos and since yesterday I have this type of error. Sometimes this error comes back to me ... what can it be related to?

Can it be related to this metric situation?

[image]

I think no because i increased the RU / s so that I have enough for each physical partition.

But I always get the same error. I thought it was a problem related to low RU / s, but it isn't.

I use the current code:

```
try
                {
                    client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, tripDocument.id));
                    CommonAzureCosmosDB.LogAzCDBCall(Convert.ToInt32(tripDocument.genKey.Split('_')[0]), "CreateTripDocument_read", tripDocument.genKey, DateTime.Now);
                }
                catch (DocumentClientException de)
                {
                    if (de.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document doc = client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName), tripDocument).Result.Resource;
                        ret[0] = doc.Id;
                        CommonAzureCosmosDB.LogAzCDBCall(Convert.ToInt32(tripDocument.genKey.Split('_')[0]), "CreateTripDocument_httpNotFound", tripDocument.genKey, DateTime.Now);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw (new Exception("DocumentClientException != HttpStatusCode.NotFound"));
                    }
                }
```

The element to load:

*{"genKey":"428_2020_24-2020-26-1012817","id":null,"dataType":"realCoords","emailStop":"ufficiotrasporti@centraleadr.coop.it","mobilePhoneStop":"","targetCoordinateStop":[13.505125,43.604742],"coordinate":[12.3573497,44.137045],"customerIntCode":562,"coordinateDate":"2020-12-03 14:02:00","coordinateDateAcq":"2020-12-03 14:05:00","plateNumber":"GA115MF","positionApprox":null,"logicOrder":"r_20201203140827779"}*

The partition key is: genKey, formed by user_year_tripNumber

Comment: Are you trying to load an document with ```"id":null```?

Comment: No id are a different meaning... the routine works untill yesterday. 
Could it be a problem with some corrupted physical partition?
Why the error does it only in some cases ..

Comment: Do you have more error descriptions. F.e. the status code. If I remember right we had the same probleme when Cosmos distributed internally the partitions then we received a 410 or 408.